# Quarkus Java Docker application ignores HTTP messages

Tags: java, http, jvm, quarkus

I'm not really sure whenever it's a Quarkus bug or JVM, but however...
We have a Quarkus application running on Docker container with OpenJDK 11 JVM on Kubernetes. Some messages seems to be ignored but JVM and after a lot of days of debugging I cannot still find the problem.
What I've noticed, when running tcpdump on docker container, I see that the IP message is received and ACKed by the network layer, but after that there is nothing... JVM doesn't take the message in account and it's not processed at all. I already tried JMX to see if there are any blocked threads, but there are nothing blocked and the message seems to be completely ignored (still cannot understand how it could happen).
The only thing we notice, that it happens just after receiving a huge message?
Maybe someone have a similar problem? May be some useful configuration to change?
I tried activating all logs, but still no trace about this message...

If someone have an idea how to debug it, can you please share?

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated :)
Thank you in advance!

there is the tcpdump:

```
08:36:17.156457 IP 10-244-0-3.nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller.ingress.svc.cluster.local.44794 > insuoapigateway-5f875fb7f7-6jxzp.80: Flags [P.], seq 66943:68633, ack 228, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 162784478 ecr 1551572
039], length 1690: HTTP
E.....@.@...
...
..a...P(.....Y............
        ...\{.GPATCH /auth/refresh/60e32119d87896001108d3e2 HTTP/1.1
Host: test.api.insuo.be
X-Request-ID: 48a13944a3f0c8b6afbb3a0319707d3a
X-Real-IP: 194.78.44.220
X-Forwarded-For: 194.78.44.220
.....

{"refreshToken":"f3b55b3c20c6a6b770a7a456ce259fbefef8b450fbc48a8c33293aa9fcf879e37afc332416fde34f11487a3816bd14e16276ccd9759298012704227d1d8fd63dcfecce5046314f9cdab0ec3c19243ae68b34e69d1c888b6a7719ffcfbdc87fcfc44f2a1ddec0c4f3acb586e
86962daf7647f6b10890df2a71194b28a74a48ebb8d9ec980577907e714a9a6a3319aeb966d416b01f91969b06f1fc3965871e45fc8ae8c01db37fb51ae799e931bc2316e0f87f64386b6483fc83178d85001ec9b388127a0fe8ac597b545db05a683f5721f86ed178412778b821a9003630088b
9175771de8692b20ec3e11f41fe3eeb92a135b7b5178fdc4a9f52f6c9bef36305"}
08:36:17.156469 IP insuoapigateway-5f875fb7f7-6jxzp.80 > 10-244-0-3.nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller.ingress.svc.cluster.local.44794: Flags [.], ack 68633, win 527, options [nop,nop,TS val 1551572127 ecr 162784478], length 0
E..4..@.@.Q.
..a
....P....Y.(........r.....
\{..    ...
08:37:17.103429 IP 10-244-0-3.nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller.ingress.svc.cluster.local.44790 > insuoapigateway-5f875fb7f7-6jxzp.80: Flags [F.], seq 1621, ack 622, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 162844424 ecr 1551572071], l
ength 0
E..4.2@.@.5F
...
..a...PBQ..Np._.....r.....
        ...\{.g
```

as you can see the IP packet is being ACKed by the network layer, but afterwards nothing happens during 1min

Comment: What do you mean by huge?, and what quarkus version are you using?, are you using rest or websockets? its a multipart/message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.